# ненужные файлы codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

в codeblocks при работе создается куча ненужных файлов вроде:

```
main_build_log.html
main.depend
main.save
```

И так для каждого файла с которым работаешь, из-за чего сложно ориентироваться по папке. как можно сделать чтобы эти файлы создавались в другую папку проекта.

Comment: Из этих файлов у меня создавался только `.depend`. Можно подробнее, что вы делаете и как?

Comment: просто пишу программу в файл .save автоматически каждые несколько минут сохраняется текущий файл, в build_log пишутся ошибки при компиляции. я не против этих файлов, и не хотел бы их убрать полностью, а лишь переместить в другую папку

Comment: Тогда просто создайте подкаталог в каталоге проекта и туда складывайте все Ваши файлы. А каталог проекта пусть содержит только служебные.